# What are the best practices to prevent staff taking over user accounts by editing the email address?

Tags: passwords, security, crm

We are building a CRM type app although this would apply to any application where there are "members" and "staff" e.g. a shopping site, dating site, facebook etc.

In our app, users can change their password the usual way, by resetting it with email confirmation. Users can also have more than one email address associated with their account.

What we are trying to work out is how to prevent staff using the system taking over the accounts. We want staff to be able to edit the email address (because someone may phone in and request a change); the issue then is they can simply change the email to one they control - and request a password re-set as a user.

Are there any recommended best practices for this?

Comment: You need to trust your staff.  Logging can also help.

Answer (score 2):

You could require the user to also authenticate the action by other means, such as when the email address is changed the user is sent a confirmation code via text message that they must input somewhere.

Another means would be to only allow access to the account if certain information is inputted correctly.  This could be address information or DOB.  It is unlikely that this information could be guessed from something like a name or account number.

Comment: For us this is information we would want staff to see. The issue for us is that staff can see all details about the user; but not certain actions the user takes (e.g. some orders they have made); so there would not be information about the user that would be secret.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add one of those silly security questions like "What is your favorite color?" and store the answer, encrypted, in the database. Staff could edit the email to their heart's content, but if they didn't know the answer to the secret question the system wouldn't let them change the password. If you have concerns about staff trustworthiness, then you need to introduce something outside their control that serves as a final gateway before you can change the user account.

I imagine a simple implementation would simply check to see if the user reset their password. If so, on login, it challenges them with the security question to "authenticate" them before allowing them to proceed.

2) Logging, monitoring, and auditing. Record which staff accounts accessed the email address change form, what address(es) they changed, what they changed them too, and when they changed them. Also record the connection information of the people accessing the accounts. If your logs show one IP address accessing 4-5 completely disparate accounts, you might need to look into that. (Yes, I know you can use proxies etc. to mask this. Not perfect but it'd weed out the chaff pretty fast).

3) Hire trustworthy people! #2 should really only need to be used as a "check" against abuse instead of the end all be all to stop it.